# Custom RSpec argument matcher spec output

Tags: ruby, rspec

I am trying to get a good output for a custom matcher I wrote:

```rb
RSpec::Matchers.define :scope_limited_to do |expected|
  match do |actual|
    @actual = actual.limit_value
    expected == @actual
  end

  failure_message do |actual|
    "expected scope to be limited to #{expected}, but was limited to #{actual} instead"
  end
end
```

Things work perfectly when using regular expectation:

```rb
expect(scope).to scope_limited_to(10)

# output
     Failure/Error: expect(scope).to scope_limited_to(10)
       expected scope to be limited to 10, but was limited to 11 instead
```

But when I use this matcher as an argument matcher:

```rb
expect(PlayerCsv).to receive(:new).with(scope_limited_to(10))

# output
     Failure/Error: PlayerCsv.new(players).perform

       #<PlayerCsv (class)> received :new with unexpected arguments
         expected: (scope limited to 10)
              got: (#<ActiveRecord::Relation [#<Player id: 136, username: "user1", birthdate: "2001-05-13", email: "email..._id: nil, player_merged_to_id: nil, inventory_access_toggled: nil, seon_registration_session: nil>]>)
```

Is there any way to improve the "got" part of the spec output? Ideally I'd like to see "(scope limited to 11)".

Comment: Can you please double check all the important information is in your post? You said something about a regular expression, but there's nothing about this in the code. And what is the test about `PlayerCsv` actually trying to do; I don't follow -- could you include some more context?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.